# Custom UserControl's click event does not fire

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

So I created a custom `UserControl` just out of a `PictureBox` and a `RadioButton`, something like the following:

```
public partial class Foo : UserControl
{
    //some declared properties for the designer...
}
```

[image]

Now I added this object to a `Form` and subscribed to it's `Click()` event.

```
private void customAddedContr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

But just clicking on this *red marked part* fires the `Click()` event.

[image]

So just by clicking on the `UserControl` itself, so when a click is performed on the `PictureBox` or `RadioButton` this `Click()` event does not get fired. I thought that the `Click` event for this new `UserControl` gets fired for each click aiming to this Window Handle.

So do I need to bind the `PictureBox`'s and `RadioButton`'s `Click()` event to the `UserControl`'s `Click()` event earlier on or what do I oversee?

---

**Edit:**

For understanding purpose, here is a colored picture of the `CustomControl`.

[image]

The top dark grey part is the `PictureBox`. The blue one is the `UserControl` itself on which I placed the other controls. The light grey bottom is the `RadioButton`. So just clicking on the blue part (`UserControl`) fires the `Click()` event.

Comment: What are you even talking about?  What PictureBox?  Which part of your image is your custom control and which is the form?  This is totally confusing.

Comment: In winforms, events does bubble up - that includes the `Click` event.
You have to handle the `PictureBox` and the `Button` click in the code of the userControl, and raise it's `Click` event yourself.

Comment: @rory.ap I updated the question with a new illustration.

Comment: @ZoharPeled So binding the `Click` events of the `PictureBox` and `RadioButton` to the `UserControl`'s `Click()` event? Or what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say the don't bubble up. You need to write the event handlers for the picurebox and radio button click event, and in that event handler raise the click event of the userControl.

Comment: *A* single RadioButton on a UserControl wont work to allow the user to select only one of several of these UCs....if that is where you are headed

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend exposing the picturebox and radio buttons click events separately.

You raise your own events for the radio and picturebox at the usercontrol level and inside each click even you would raise the controls events. then you handle those click events outside the control and respond accordingly.

```
public partial class Foo : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler RadioButtonClicked;
    public event EventHandler PictureBoxClicked:
}
```

then in the picturebox or button click event inside the control you raise the individual event at the control level

```
private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PictureBoxClicked != null)
        PictureBoxClicked(sender, e);
}
```